# Error when installing package with composer but package seems installed anyway

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, package, fullcalendar

I'm trying to install the package maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar (Laravel helper for FullCalendar.io) with composer.
So here is the command I run:

'''
 php ../../composer.phar require maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar
'''

And here is the result:

> Using version ^1.3 for maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar
>
> ./composer.json has been updated
>
> Loading composer repositories with package information
>
> Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>
> Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
>     - Installing maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar (v1.3.0): Downloading (100%)
>   Package phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
>
> Writing lock file
>
> Generating autoload files
>
> php artisan clear-compiled
>
> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
>     Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::getCachedCompilePath()
>
> Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 255

But now I wonder if the package is installed or not, because it now appears in my list of installed packages.

If anyone has the answer, thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have `vendor/compiled.php` file or `storage/framework/compiled.php`? Which versions of Laravel are you on?

Comment: What makes you think it is not installed, it looks fine? You can verify the install, just look in the vendor folder of your project.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, indeed it seems to be well installed. (I'm on Laravel 5.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to delete file `compiled.php` in your vendor directory manually, and then it started to work again.